# Issues with using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am trying to use socket.io for the first time, Im using it with a MEAN Stack. I have set it up the following way.

**Server.js**

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.listen(port);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.emit('message', {
        'message': 'hello world'
    });
});
```

**HTML File**

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log(data.message);
});
</script>
```

I couldn't find the `socket.io.js` file so I searched for a CDN for the script. I used the following.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.6/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I tried downloading the socket.io.js from their website but the website seems to be down. I can access it, I get the **502 BAD GATEWAY** error (http://socket.io)

When I load my HTML page after setting everything up as shown above I get the following error in the console.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `socket.io` server will perform some magic to provide that file when you retrieve it like this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**: ah, I see the problem: your Express setup is incorrect.

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = require('socket.io')(server);

app.listen(port);
```

You're attaching `socket.io` to a server created by `http.createServer`, but with `app.listen()` you're actually creating a *new* server, one that `socket.io` isn't attached to.

You can make the setup a bit simpler:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = app.listen(port);
var io      = require('socket.io')(server);
```

No need to use `http`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried that it gives the similar error in the browser console along with `io is not defined`

Comment: And you're including that file before you're using your own script?

Comment: yes, I first add the file and then below it I type my own `var socket = io.connect()` script.

Comment: Can you make sure that `/socket.io/socket.io.js` is actually loaded properly?

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn never mind, it was actually another problem. See my edit.

Comment: Perfect that worked! Thanks for the help! Learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

As of now, socket.io website is still down. If you don't have the file in your server, it does not help using `/socket.io/` because this points to a route on your server and that route doesn't seem to exist on your app. With this config, you need to be serving the .js file statically from your server - but I don't see that on your server code.

When you try the CDN, make sure the file is being loaded.

Comment: The `socket.io` server will automatically add a route to handle `/socket.io/socket.io.js`, there's no need to do that manually.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that! A bit off topic, but it seems their website is down for an unusually long time...

Comment: Yeah I have no idea why, it's been offline for days now. Almost get the idea that no one seems to care :-(